# Memory (hex) address being returned instead of value in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, formtastic

I'm definitely a bit of a noob, so this might be something simple that I'm overlooking, however, the searches that I've done to try and find a solution have come up empty.

I've built a form using formtastic that has 5 input fields: two are text boxes and three are select lists.

```
<%= semantic_form_for @player do |f| %>
<%= f.inputs do %>
    <%= f.input :firstname, :label => "First Name " %>
    <%= f.input :lastname, :label => "Last Name " %>
    <%= f.input :leagueid, :as => :select, :collection => League.all(:order => :leaguename), :label => "League " %>
    <%= f.input :team_1, :as => :select, :collection => Team.all(:order => :name), :label => "Team 1 " %>
    <%= f.input :team_2, :as => :select, :collection => Team.all(:order => :name), :label => "Team 1 " %>
<% end %>
    <%= f.actions %>
  <% end %>
```

What is happening is that the Teams lists work perfectly (the team names are displayed). However, the League list is a different story. All of the entries in the list look like this (with different a different code after 'League:'):

```
#<League:0x007fe29c406498>
```

If I use the form to create a Player, it works fine. The correct league ID goes into the database and everything. I just can't figure out why the names of the teams show, while whatever-that-is shows for the league.

Any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

When converting objects to String, Ruby will convert them to the memory address like you see unless you provide a `to_s` method for string conversions. I haven't used formtastic, but I believe adding a `to_s` method to your League class should cause it to display what you want.

Try adding

```
def to_s
  @name    # use whatever you want to be displayed. 
end
```

to the League class.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had tried adding .to_s to League.all, but that causes nothing to show up in the list.

I then tried adding the def you provided (using @leaguename, which is the column name), but it didn't change the result.

Comment: I see.  I added a separate answer that takes a very different approach. Hope it helps. Curious how the team selections work fine, but not league.

Comment: You know, that's what's driving me nuts too! In fact, after I typed my reply, I had the idea of putting Team where League is and changing :leaguename to :name without changing anything else and it worked. The teams showed up in all three places. I'm guess it's gotta be a database issue. I might rebuild the table and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

You could try explicitly specifying the fields that should be used as the text and id within the select list. I believe it would look like.

```
<%= f.input :leagueid, :as => :select, :collection => Hash[League.all.map { |league| [league.leaguename, league.id] }]
```

The syntax is crazy. The call to map is returning an array of name/id pairs, like `[ ['league1', 1], ['league2', 2] ]`. Calling `Hash` on that converts it to a hash, like `{'league1' => 1, 'league2' => 2}`. Seems like the select list should use this hash to populate itself.

There's an example of this at http://rdoc.info/github/justinfrench/formtastic, under the Usage section.

Comment: I just tried this and it worked! Thank you so much for your help. I'm still going to dig into it because I'm curious why it didn't work the first time. Thanks again.

Comment: Good to hear. My guess is formtastic looks for a field named 'name' and uses it as the textual description in the list. That might explain why Team worked, but League didn't. I noticed there's a :member_label option that might help you. Looks like it would work like this: `<%= f.input :leagueid, :as => :select, :collection => League.all(:order => :leaguename), :label => "League ", :member_label => :leaguename %>`. If this answer helped you, please mark it correct so it displays before the other answer I posted that didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

:member_name is the solution I think.

```
<%= f.input :leagueid, :as => :select, :collection => League.all(:order => :leaguename), :label => "League " %>
```

Will probably work for you as

```
<%= f.input :leagueid, :as => :select, :member_name => :league, :collection => League.all(:order => :leaguename), :label => "League " %>
```

My problem was I have a model with a field the same name as the model and I think that confused Formtastic

Example scaffold:

```
  rails g scaffold Countries code:string country:string
  rails g scaffold Types title:string description:string
```

Model:

```
class Sign < ActiveRecord::Base   
attr_accessible :title, :country_id, :type_id 
belongs_to :country   
belongs_to :type
```

Form View:

```
<%= f.input :type %>
<%= f.input :country, :member_label => :country  %>
```

Having a form without the member_label leads to the object id displaying in the select box for countries although the ID is correctly saved.  The type select worked perfectly without declaring member_label.
Note that I didn't need to specify `:as => :select` as formtastic can deduce this from the belongs_to relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Try using :

```
<%= form.input :league, :member_label => :leaguename %>
```

This will override the naming convention of the Formtastic Column Select.
Have a look also at : [Overriding the Column Name Convention wiki](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic/wiki/1.1-How-It-Works)

Hope this helped.